# Where to find Scottish birth records from 1905?

Tags: birth-records, scotland, 1900s-decade

I'm using family search and also find my past at the moment as they're both free for me to use. I'm looking for the birth certificate of my great granddad Alexander Barclay Ormond born circa 1905 in Angus, Scotland.

I can find his military record from the Tank Corps in 1925, but can't find a birth certificate. I'm assuming this is something to do with the records in Scotland not being available? If so, where can I find the Scottish records, ideally without having to pay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Scotland's People](https://www.scotlandspeople.gov.uk) is always a good place to start for Scottish records. You'll need to register to use the site. Searching is free, but you have to buy credits to see actual documents/images. A "Births" search using the exact name in your question brings up just one result:

> ORMOND ALEXANDER BARCL M 1905 288/A 17 Forfar

It may be worth searching with less precise parameters, but this looks like a good bet for your great grandfather.

Comment: Cheers, I'll make an account. Its rewarding to be building up an arsenal of tools with which to find info